# Angular 5: how to refer to a subcomponent method from a parent component HTML template?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have a dialog subcomponent DeleteAssociationDialog with an openDeleteAssociationDialog method in it:

**delete-association-dialog.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-delete-association-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'delete-association-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['delete-association-dialog.component.css']
})
export class DeleteAssociationDialogComponent {

  constructor(
  public dialog: MatDialog,
  public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DeleteAssociationDialogComponent>) { }

  openDeleteAssociationDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeleteAssociationDialogComponent, {
      width: '250px'
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
    });
  }
}
```

The dialog should be shown when clicked on a button in the parent component (app.component) HTML, I am using @ViewChild to establish a reference:

**app.component.html** [fragment]

```
<button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="child.openDeleteAssociationDialog()">
  <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
</button>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DeleteAssociationDialogComponent } from './delete-association-dialog/delete-association-dialog.component';

import { MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DeleteAssociationDialogComponent,
  ],
  entryComponents: [DeleteAssociationDialogComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,
    FormsModule
    MatDialogModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { DeleteAssociationDialogComponent } from './delete-association-dialog/delete-association-dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css', './app.component.panel.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('DeleteAssociationDialogComponent') child: DeleteAssociationDialogComponent;
}
```

Getting an error --
"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDeleteAssociationDialog' of undefined"

What am I missing? How do I properly refer to a subcomponent **method** from a parent component HTML template?

Comment: why do you want to? this sounds like bad practice

Comment: please add your `/app.component.html` code

Comment: the idea was to compartmentalize dialog components, as I don't really want to have more than one @ Component in app.component.ts. I am new to Angular, so not yet that familiar with its best practices, but having multiple @ Component for each dialog I have in a single  app.component.ts seemed like a bad practice for sure :)

Comment: @OvidiuDolha added its fragment where the method is called

Comment: @porgo I tried that and got 'NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!', I also read that it's not needed for dialogs

Comment: try to add MatDialogRef to providers array in app.module.ts

Comment: @porgo that leads to an error "Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MatDialogRef: (?, ?, ?, ?)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem stems from the fact that the method to open the dialog is contained within the dialog itself. So that method won't exist unless the dialog is already opened...the dialog component is both the chicken and the egg.

The solution is to move the method to `openDeleteAssociationDialogComponent` to the parent.

And then it's simple:

```
<button (click)="openDeleteAssociationDialogComponent()"></button>
```

If you want to abstract it away to make the dialog-opening button reusable, you can do something like:

**component.html**

```
<association-deleter></association-deleter>
```

**component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'association-deleter',
  template: `<button (click)="openDialog()"></button>`
})
export class DeleteAssociationComponent {
  constructor(
    public dialog: MatDialog,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DeleteAssociationDialogComponent>
  ){}

  openDeleteAssociationDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeleteAssociationDialogComponent, {
      width: '250px'
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');
    });
  }
}
```

Then you could reuse the button which opens the delete association dialog.

Comment: the problem I am dealing with is that I am unable to refer to a subcomponent method from parent component HTML and I can't refer to a subcomponent selector in parent component HTML either. It looks like I am doing something non-idiomatic way, but I can't imagine an architecture of a single main component with on-click references from parent component HTML to methods in subcomponents is something out of the ordinary.. do people just lump all dialog code into a single component?

Comment: You are able to refer to a subcomponent method, assuming that method is public and the child is defined. However, you are currently trying to call a method on the dialog which doesn't exist until it's opened. See my updated answer for a couple of options that will work for you.

Comment: Glad I could help -- consider up voting to show it was helpful and / or marking it as accepted so others know your question was answered. Welcome to SO :)